# What is the best way to handle no ID errors in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my controllers I use something like this a lot to verify that a `project` really belongs to a given `user`:

```
private

def authorized_user
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@project.user)
end
```

This works great because user A cannot see the projects of user B (he is being forwarded to the root page instead).

However, this works only as long as `project` URLs are requested that really exist.

For example, the URL `http://localhost:3000/projects/1` will either display the user's project OR forward to the root URL (if another user tries to access the project).

But when I try to access a project that doesn't exist **at all** in the database, e.g. like this:

`http://localhost:3000/projects/777`

... I get an ugly `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error:

`Couldn't find Person with id=777`

What would be the best way to improve the user experience here?

I have never actually *deployed* a Rails project yet, so I don't even know what this error will look like in production mode.

Can anybody help?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

I personally like to use this:

```
@project = Project.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

If project does not exist, `@project` will be nil.

Comment: OK, thanks! What exactly does `first` do in this case? I thought `first` selects the first record... But I'm a n00b...

Comment: Well, to remedy your noobishness, read this guide: [Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). You'll find the answer there. :)

Comment: OK, I understand. It returns `nil` rather than throwing an exception. But I have to test for nil values in the next line then...

Comment: OK, adding this makes it work quite well: `redirect_to root_path unless @person && current_user?(@person.user)` I guess I have to do that in all my controllers now?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to handle it, you can use

```
@project = Project.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

This will let @project be nil if no records found and you will manually have to handle the case.

Another solution is to throw an 404 which makes sense as the resource isn't there. You can easily do this in any controller (or the application controller) by using:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

This would result into something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ..
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

The latter solution will show the user the default 404(NOT FOUND) error page. In the first case you have more control but at the cost of doing it everywhere

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think your second solution is much better, because it doesn't involve modifying scaffold-generated code and can be implemented cleanly with just a few lines in the application controller.

Comment: You mean Sergio's solution is better? OK, but how would I add this in the application controller?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to avoid not authorized users to access projects, you should scope your find methods:

```
current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
```

This way you will get "Couldn't find Project with id" error in development. To avoid this, you can use:

```
current_user.projects.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

which returns `nil` instead of exception, but there are good reasons why you normally should not. In a well-written rails app the only time any user would access a project he shouldn't is when he manually changed the id in the url. You want this to be reported in your logs, not silently skipped over.

Finally, to throw 403 Forbidden instead of 404 Not Found, you may consider using one of many authorization gems ([`cancan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by Ryan Bates comes to mind).

Edit: Oh, and in production, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound will render 404.html page, a.k.a. these are not the projects you are looking for.

Comment: Very good point you made here. Thanks a lot for your help! Wow, got quite a few really good answers to choose from in this thread...

Comment: Just to be clear about redirecting the response to 404.html - they are great examples how to change the default behaviour, but they are not needed in this case. As I said, in production Rails does that by default. And in development you want to get the exception page, not the 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
  # Render 404 page when record not found
    def render_404      
       render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => 404
    end
end
```